# Can't login to Ubuntu One from gnome-control-center (20.04)

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-control-center

```
viator@viator-acronis-laptop:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ gnome-control-center -v
14:23:51.0206                      GLib:    DEBUG: setenv()/putenv() are not thread-safe and should not be used after threads are created
14:23:51.0219      diagnostics-cc-panel:    DEBUG: ABRT vanished
14:24:08.0178                      GLib:    DEBUG: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested) (child_setup specified) 
14:24:08.0236                GoaBackend:  WARNING: Error logging in snapd: (most recent call last): (snapd-error-quark, 10)

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04 LTS"

viator@viator-acronis-laptop:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ snap version
snap    2.45.1+20.04
snapd   2.45.1+20.04
series  16
ubuntu  20.04
kernel  5.4.0-41-generic

gnome-control-center 3.36.3
```

But, I can login from gnome-software and snap login.
I have an active authorization:

```
snap whoami 
email: viator@via-net.org
```

Comment: Should I create a bug? As I can see nobody know how to fix it.